# how to print all element in a vector in one message in C++?

Tags: c++

I have a vector of struct and I need print them in a nice format, currently I have:

```
int k = 1; 
std::cout<< "my vector names are :" std::endl ; 
for( auto v : vec1){
                std::cout<< k++  << v.name << std::endl ;  
            }
```

and it gives me :

```
my vector names are :
1 name1 
2 name2
```

...
but I would like to have

```
my vector names are : 1 name1 2 name2 ...
```

and also can I just use one std::cout to get "my vector names are " and all names?
thanks!

Comment: leave off the endl

Comment: If the elements of your vector can be inserted into an ostream with `<<` you can copy the vector to a `std::ostream_iterator`, but that still doesn't take care of the leading print in one statement.

Comment: After the `for` loop, do a `std::cout << "\n";`.

Answer (score 1):

If your vector contents are able to be inserted into an output stream, you can use `std::copy` with a `std::ostream_iterator` to get close to what you're describing.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>

struct A {
  int x;
  std::string y;
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& o, const A& a) {
  return o << a.x << ": " << a.y;
}

int main() {
  std::vector<A> v { {1, "hello"}, {2, "world"} };

  std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), std::ostream_iterator<A>(std::cout, ", "));
  std::cout << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Running this:

```
$ ./a.out
1: hello, 2: world,
$
```